# Print a numpy array with parentheses instead of brackets

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array, a, how can  i print it so the values are surrounded by parentheses instead of brackets?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> print(a)
[1 2 3]
```

I would like

```
>>> print(whatever)
(1 2 3)
```

Comment: I don't know why OP would want this repr. Anyway, tuple will still have commas.

Comment: Actually, `print '(%s)' % ' '.join(map(str, a))` or `print('({})'.format(str(a)[1:-1]))`?

Comment: Automated checker for school expects this output. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option, as noted in the comments above (@Psidom) is to

- convert the numpy output to a string using `str()`.
- then manually replace the opening bracket and closing bracket with parenthesis using `replace()`. `replace()` is a string method

  `import numpy as np
  a = np.array([1,2,3])
  print(a)
  [1 2 3]
  print(str(a).replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')'))
  (1 2 3)`

In this case, `str()` converts the output from numpy to the string representation so that you can take advantage of the various string methods associated with strings.

With the output converted to a string, you can then immediately call the `replace()` method... since the output of the `replace()` method is also a string, you can chain `replace()` methods sequentially to do multiple replacements.

Alternatives to using chained `replace()` methods would be to create a regular expression and use something like `re.sub()`, but that seems like overkill for a simple case like this.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` uses `[]` just as `list` does.  Structured array records are marked with `()` to highlight their difference:

```
In [286]: a = np.array([1,2,3])
In [287]: a.view('i,i,i')
Out[287]: 
array([(1, 2, 3)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

Extracting a record gives a tuple like display:

```
In [288]: a.view('i,i,i')[0]
Out[288]: (1, 2, 3)

In [289]: tuple(a.tolist())
Out[289]: (1, 2, 3)
```

There's isn't a normal display that uses `()` and omits the commas.  To get that you need to do your own formatting, or perform some sort of replace on the common display.

If the checker expects `()` and no comma, there's something wrong.  That's not normal.